# How do I trigger a notification from a phonegap app without a push service?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I have followed along the [tutorial on the PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/push-notifications/#explaining-push), which worked fine with their example app, but when making my own app I can't figure out how to get the `PushNotification` object into my single-page-app.

I am guessing that Phonegap is building a mysterious *cordova.js* file based on the *config.xml*, and that the `PushNotification` is added to the root `window` scope inside this mystery file.

So far I have tried...

- Including `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in my *www/index.html*
- Made sure `<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push"`... is in my *config.xml* file
- Added `if (typeof PushNotification === 'undefined') { alert("No PushNotification"); }` to my app's JavaScript. This always seems to fire, both when testing locally in a browser (the cordova file is obviously not found), and testing via the PhoneGap app on an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
  console.log('notification event');
  navigator.notification.alert(
    data.message,         // message
    null,                 // callback
    data.title,           // title
    'Ok'                  // buttonName
  );
});
```

The above event handler will be triggered called **only** when the app receives a push notification (the notification event).

When you are using the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/) that is how it is developed.
You **cannot** trigger it otherwise. It happens only when the push notification is received.

You can just add the plugin and add these lines in your app. This should recieve notifications properly.
Add plugin using either cordova or phonegap according to your app,

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push 
phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

then initiate `PushNotification` directly in your `js` file after `OnDeviceReady`,

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
         "senderID": "XXXXXXXX" //Your sendeer ID from Firebase Cloud Messenger (FCM)
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId 
    //store this in your server for future use
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem I'm having is that `PushNotification` is undefined, even though `"phonegap-plugin-push"` is in the `config.xml`, and I'm trying to setup the notifications after `deviceready`... still no `PushNotification`. It's probably because I'm testing on the local web version of the app.

Comment: ohh alright, just in case :- Check your net connections on the device before running the app. The `init()` function needs internet for registering the device on the FCM. I had forgot this many times and got `PushNotification is not available` error..